# Retrieve only unique values in search web part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, search, search-results, result-source

I have added a search webpart on the webpart page. For which, I have defined a result source and associated it with some content type which points to a list.

This helps me retrieve all the items from the list. But I want the items which have the same `Title` to be shown only once.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, what condition do I need to add?

Also, on exploring I have found something as 'TrimDuplicates' properties. Can this be of some help?

Comment: Or do you really want only one search result of each item even if it's the same title? If so add crawl rules which includes AllItems.aspx and a rule which excludes all other view pages.

Comment: If you are talking about list views. I have only one view for the list i.e. `AllItems` view. And yes, I want only one result per `Title`.